# I am reading the CNC Programs of remote machines to memory buffer. When using "Encoding.UTF8.GetString" german & turkish characters cannot be read

Tags: c#

I have a Blazor Server App. Here I am reading out the CNC Programs of remote machines to a memory buffer. When using "Encoding.UTF8.GetString" german & turkish characters cannot be read correctly. For this characters I get a question mark in a black diagonal square � when I show the program output on my blazor razor page.
Blazor razor.cs code:

```
 result = AGL4.NCK_CopyFromNCAlloc(connnr, path, out buff, out bufflen, timeout);     
 CNC_File_Out=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff, 0, bufflen);
 CNC_File_Out_Array = CNC_File_Out.Split("\n");
```

I am showing the CNC_File_Out_Array array elements directly on my razor page. As I explained I get � for german or turkish characters.

Comment: That means the buffer isn't using UTF8. Whatever `NCK_CopyFromNCAlloc` is, it doesn't return strings using UTF8. .NET has no problem with Unicode or UTF8 and your own question proves this. StackOverflow is a .NET web app storing data in Unicode database fields and this page is a UTF8 page like almost every other web site

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How Should I encode the buffer in this case?

Comment: How *did* you encode it? It's `NCK_CopyFromNCAlloc` that is *not* returning UTF8. We can't guess what your own method does. .NET has no problem with Unicode. .NET strings *are* Unicode. That's why I can just type Αυτό Εδώ knowing it will appear just fine. There's no `NCK_CopyFromNCAlloc` in .NET, that's a custom method in your own code or a third-party library. Googling for this returns only 3 hits, and one is this question

Comment: If you don't know what encoding is used, you'll have to guess and try until you find which single-byte encoding/codepage works. There's no single codepage that covers both German and Turkish. You can use `Encoding.Latin1` to decode bytes using the Latin1/ISO-8859-1 codepage. For Turkish try `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9")`. A better solution would be to configure that third-party library to use UTF8 or UTF16 instead of a single-byte codepage